# how to get products according to their category

Tags: php, mysql, categories, product

I have made recently a catalog which have 2 categories (nokia,samsung)Now I want that when user click on nokia so nokia products should be appear and when user click on samsung so samsung products should be apeear please help me with detail code.Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the code you've tried - the purpose of this site is to improve/correct your existing code, not write it for you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

These are all assumptions since you didn't post the total details needed eg, schema, sample records and desired result.

What you need is a `WHERE` condition in your query. What `Where` does is to filter records on your tables. Ex,

```
SELECT *                       // -- * means all columns
FROM  catalog
WHERE category = 'Nokia'
```

when you execute the sql query above, it will list all records in your table which has category under `Nokia`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your table structure

But for query optimization you should use one to many relationship for categories to products

and you can use left join for fetch data

SELECT categories.name, products.name  FROM categories LEFT JOIN products ON categories.id=products.cat_id where categories.name = "Nokia"

Answer (score 0):

You can use following sql query for get product by category....

```
SELECT c.name, p.name FROM categories as c LEFT JOIN products as p ON c.id=products.cat_id where c.name like "Nokia";
```